# Maven/AJDT project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, aspectj, m2eclipse, ajdt

I need to use aspectj in a maven project. I installed the maven plugin for eclipse (m2e), the maven aspectj plugin, and also AJDT for Eclipse. So now, when i open a new project i have "Maven Project" and "AspectJ Project". how can i make a new project that is Maven AspectJ project?
I did not found any reference for that, so you are my only hope.
thanks

Answer (score 31):

1. Go to Help > Install New Software...
2. Use this software repository: http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator/
3. Install the AJDT m2e Configurator

Source: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/10/18/upgrading-maven-integration-for-springsource-tool-suite-2-8-0/#comment-207264 (Andrew Eisenberg)

Comment: *Note*: there is a newer URL vor V2 of the connector. However, the old one works also in most of the cases I've seen...   http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator-v2/

Answer (score 6):

You should add the maven-aspectj-plugin to your build plugins section in your pom.xml as in:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844603/how-to-create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-with-aspectj-support) is also of benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Check AJDT project configurator for m2eclipse

The m2eclipse-AJDT plugin detect that the `pom.xml` contains the `aspectj-maven-plugin` and add automatically the relevant `AJDT` nature and configuration to the project when importing it in eclipse.

I think some effort have bean made for the plugin to work with version 0.12 of m2eclipse , dont know if it's worked.

I already try the plugin with m2eclipse 0.10 and it worked well.

See [GitHub m2eclipse-ajdt project](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-ajdt.git)
See [Move AJDT integration out of main m2e source tree](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1944)

Answer (score 2):

1. Firstly we need to make sure AJDT (AspectJ development tools) is installed for eclipse. Check out the latest or appropriate version of AJDT for your Eclipse. (http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/)
2. Secondly install "AJDT m2e Configurator" using this repository http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator/ (As Hendy described above).
3. **If you have previously installed m2eclipse, you need to uninstall it before performing step 2.**

Comment: It doesn't really work to me, neither installing AJDT before m2eclipse nor after it. I come up with this error: "The following plugin will not be installed" and instead it suggest me another 2 plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the relevant project facets to your project configuration in eclipse after adding the AspectJ support in your maven `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the aspectj-maven-plugin in your pom.xml you'll get one missing m2e connector :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*aj</include>
                    <include>**/*java</include>
                </includes>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <weaveDependency>
                        <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
                        <classifier>log4jonly</classifier>
                    </weaveDependency>
                </weaveDependencies>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I had to install m2e AJDT maven plugin configurator in eclipse but it did not work at first because I had missing dependencies.
So to start install the AJDT tool available on this site : http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/48/dev/update/
Restart eclipse and then the install of m2e AJDT maven plugin configurator should work. After a new restart you should have eclipse available to build your aspectj classes.